# Key error, parse error using *.agg method

Tags: pandas, datetime, time-series

Suppose I have a dataframe of some stock price where the column 'Open' is the 0th column and 'Close' is the 3rd column.  Suppose further that I want to find the maximum difference between Close and Open price.  That can be done easily without using the  `agg` method, but let me show what the error is when I use them.

```
def daily_value(df):
    df.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:,3] - df.iloc[:, 0]
    return df.max()

def daily_value(df):
    df['Open'] = df['Close'] - df['Open']
    return df.max()
```

Both work as to replace the 0th column, namely 'Open', and return the maximum difference between Open and Close.
This works fine when I have `df1` and I type `daily_value(df1)`.

However, when I try `df1.agg(daily_value)`, both version fail.  The first says `IndexingError: Too many indexers` while the latter say `KeyError: Close`.

How do I proceed if I indeed need to pass the function into *.agg method?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide axis. Aggregration function call needs axis. You should call your function with

```
df1.agg(daily_value, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sorry, axis = 1 is aggregate along each row.  My data was in column so I should use axis=0 to aggregate along each column.  But when I tried it, it doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to user agg method with function what I am understating  that you are trying to get the maximum different between 2 columns after creating the new column simply you can use df.agg({'Column name' : 'max'}
see the below example :

[image]

Comment: Yes indeed.   Thanks. I did state this in my question that this simple calculation doesn't need .agg method.  But just let's suppose that I really need to use it, namely, `df.agg(daily_value)` must be used.  How to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

1- assign df to return instead of df.max()
2- pass max as agg keyword and call the function in a print to check the result as the below
print(daily_value(df1.agg('max')))